# how to correctly write Dockerfile, and use docker-compose under a host non-root user/uid (for best practice)?

Tags: security, docker

I am not too sure how to apply security best practice(s) when using docker. Every popular guide seems to be using root.

Could anyone share an example/boilerpoint on
1. how to write a Dockerfile (for non-root user) , e.g. busybox
2, use the Dockerfile inside a docker-compose file
3. run the docker-compose with non-root user/uid

I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some different ways to achieve this.

### In the Dockerfile, create a user and run the application as that user.

This is the preferred pattern.

```
FROM <BASE>
RUN groupadd -g 1000 myuser && \
    useradd -r -u 1000 -g myuser myuser
USER myuser
...
```

### When running a container, specify its user

Sometimes you need to run an image pulled from Docker Hub. This image may not follow the pattern described above and simply run as `root`.

You can specify its user when running it.

```
docker run --user <uid>:<pid> ...
```

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

### Use userns-remap

Details of this pattern are discussed here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/